# Plotting 3D data with Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

My 3D data is stored in a .txt file as the following

```
3423.432 4353.23 45345.435
324.4    4352.2  3342.3
1234.3   3988.4  342.
...
```

so, each column corresponds to a separate axis (x, y, z). How could I plot the data in 3D with Gnuplot such that the x, y and z axis are shown for the orientation purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the [Pseudo 3D Bar graph](http://folk.uio.no/hpl/scripting/doc/gnuplot/Kawano/datafile-e.html#3dim) section on this article. You are going to use the *[splot](http://www.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html)* command, specifically created for 3D plots. The article gives you simple examples that fits with what you are looking for. The data, in the format that you already have, "X Y Z", is good too, so you do not need to tweak anything in it.

Comment: Many thanks. Since I'm allowed to change the viewpoint, how could I save the resulting image in eps format with colors?

Comment: @user506901 "set term postscript enhanced color" and "set output 'filename.ps'" :)

Comment: The referenced article here seems to be unreachable.

Comment: @RobertP.Goldman: thanks, just updated the reference. The Not So Frequently Asked Questions of Gnuplot is a having a hard time http://www.gnuplotting.org/not-so-frequently-asked-questions-site-down/